# Trying unit testing store, How to make it work?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuex

I have this store.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const mutations = {
  increment: state => state.count++,
  Changeloading(state, status) { state.loading = status },
  ChangeUserGroup(state, newGroup) { state.userGroup = newGroup; },
  ChangeOriginalRole(state, newRole) { state.originalRole = newRole; }
}
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    loading: false, //header, TeamLead, TeamMember
    listUserGroup: [],
    userRole: "",
    originalRole: "",
    userGroup: {}
  },
  mutations,
 ...
})
```

In my testing file store.spec.js

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import mutations from '@/store'

// destructure assign `mutations`
const { increment } = mutations

describe('mutations', () => {
  it('INCREMENT', () => {
    // mock state
    const state = { count: 0 }
    // apply mutation
    increment(state)
    // assert result
    expect(state.count).to.equal(1)
  })
})
```

This is the result i am getting:

mutations
    1) INCREMENT

0 passing (75ms)
  1 failing

1) mutations
       INCREMENT:
     TypeError: increment is not a function

## at Context.increment (dist\webpack:\tests\unit\store.spec.js:13:5)

EDIT (4/16/2019)

I walk down one more step. I saw here that I should "export" all the components in my store.js like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const mutations = {...};

export const state = {...};

export const actions = {...};

export const getters = {...};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
});
```

But even in that way... I'm getting the ugly (testing fail message)

0 passing (61ms)
  1 failing

1) mutations
       increment:
     TypeError: increment is not a function
      at Context.increment (dist\webpack:\tests\unit\store.spec.js:12:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer for this one:
In my test file I have

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import mutations from '@/store'
```

right way to import mutations should be...

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import {mutations} from '@/store'
```

The case was resolved :) by {  }

Regards,